# Angular 4 Function invoking and asynchronous call issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am trying to invoke one function from another function in the same component but the other doesn't return any response and other function calls get call. I don't know how to use then and promise keyword in order to wait for the response.

Please let me know where i am going wrong.

I tried every other way to get the coordinates through navigator function but it doesn't returns the coordinates but when i tried to run the same code in browser console it returns the coordinates.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, ignoreElements } from 'rxjs/operators' 
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { throwError } from 'rxjs/index' 
import { TouchSequence } from 'selenium-webdriver';
import { ThrowStmt } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Weather';
  cityName:string = 'delhi';
  backgroundImageUrl:string = '';
  weatherDetails:object = {};
  iconImageUrl:string= '';
  dataSource:any = {};
  latitude:number;
  longitude: number;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){

  }

  getUserLocation(): any {
    var obj: object = {};
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationSuccess, locationError);
   function locationSuccess(position) {
     console.log("success");
     console.log(position.coords);
     obj = position.coords;
   }
   function locationError() {
      console.log("error")
   }

   return obj;
 }

 searchCity(){
    var coords = this.getUserLocation();
    if(coords){
    this.http.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='+coords.latitude+'&lon='+coords.longitude+'&mode=json&appid=')
     .subscribe(
       ((response: any) => {
         this.dataSource = response;
         if(this.dataSource.weather.length > 0){
           this.weatherDetails = this.dataSource.weather.filter(function(el){return el})[0];
           this.switchBackground();
         }
       }),
       catchError((error) => {
          return throwError(error);
       })
     )
   }
 }

 private switchBackground(){
    var weatherId = this.weatherDetails[0].id;
    switch(weatherId){
     case 711:
      this.backgroundImageUrl = '../assets/images/01-smoke.png';
      this.iconImageUrl = '';
      break;
     case 701:
      this.backgroundImageUrl = '../assets/images/02-mist.jpg';
      this.iconImageUrl = '../assets/images/icons/01-cloudy-sky.png';
      break;
     default :
      break;
   }
 }

 // public getLocation(){
//   let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
//     resolve('resolved');
//     reject(new Error("Unable to process your request.")); // ignored
//   });
//   promise.then(function(response){
//     this.searchCity();
//   })
// } 

 ngOnInit(){
    this.getUserLocation();
  }
}
```

I expect to get http.get call with coordinates in the same but actually it coordinates gets undefined. Can you please help me out.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Show the only related code! That means two function which you need to call one after another

Comment: Or it would be better if you provide stackBlitz with expected behavior

Comment: Use Observables instead of promises

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Promise` 
check this code

```
  async ngOnInit() {
    // Use 1 use await inside an async method
    console.log(await this.getUserLocation());

    // Use 2 use promise then/catch
    this.getUserLocation().then(coords => {
      console.log(coords);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
  getUserLocation(): any {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationSuccess, locationError);
      function locationSuccess(position) {
        resolve(position.coords);
      }
      function locationError() {
        reject("error");
      }
    });

  }
```

first you have to return a new promise from your method

you `resolve` in success or when you want to return a useful data

you `reject` when you have an error

now after you created your `Promise`

you can either call it using `await` which will resolve the value for you, but you can only use await inside an `async` function

or use `then` and `catch`

`then` will return the value that you passed to `resolve` inside your promise

`catch` will return the value that you passed to `reject` inside your promise

here is a stackblitz link to tinker with

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rx9us6

p.s: you'll find the code in `home.component.ts`